# Outside the coordinate system in Div html

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, coordinates, draggable

The problem is that when you leave the block. Down and right - the scroll appears. And when you go left and up - there is none.
And it is needed (the code below can be run and checked)

```js
$(function () {
    $("#draggable3").draggable({});
});
```

```css
.generic-container {
 height: 95vh;
  width: 100vh;
  overflow: scroll;
 background-color: #aaa;
  position: relative; 
 
}


#draggable3{
  height: 40vh;
  width: 40vh;
  background-color: #fff;
 position: absolute;
 left: 28%;
 top: 28%;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<body>

<div class="generic-container">
    <div id='draggable3' class="draggable">
        
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Limit the movement of the parameter - "containment: 'parent'" It does not suit me

Comment: @Mr Lister, Any. I just need show scroll bars whe i draggin element #draggable3 in the top or left side

Comment: @Mr Lister, n1 joke man) i need to showing scroll when element goes to the left side or/and top side. "Overflow.  auto" - showing  scrollbar when element goes down or right

Answer (score 0):

Add `scroll: false` option and remove `overflow: scroll;` from your css.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#draggable3").draggable({
    containment: ".generic-container",
    scroll: false
  });
});
```

```css
.generic-container {
  height: 95vh;
  width: 100vh;
  background-color: #aaa;
  position: relative;
}

#draggable3 {
  height: 40vh;
  width: 40vh;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 28%;
  top: 28%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<body>

  <div class="generic-container">
    <div id='draggable3' class="draggable">

    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I said that "containment: .generic-container" should not be included in my project!

Comment: @mr-lister, "containment: 'parent'" and "containment: .generic-container" - are the same.     I dont need to block my draggable element, I NEED scroll bars when i dragging my element in top or left side